# Long eth. cable working only when connected directly to PC

Tags: router, performance, internet, ethernet, modem

I have this 80m cat5 cable that is plugged into modem, when i plug it into PC directly, internet works fine, but when i connect it to router TP-Link TL-WR841N, internet slows down to unusable speed. I have tried factory reset- nothing. Cable is soldered on 1 spot and also at the end connector is soldered to wires, but it should be no problem as it works at PC. Thanks

Comment: How's the speed when using a short cable with the same router?

Comment: have you confirmed that the cable is straight-through cable, not crossover?

Comment: @FrankThomas it works when i plug it into pc so it has to be ok. 5 Mbit/s when connected long to pc or short, and 3 Mbit/s on router. It has been working for 1 year straight and now it doesn't, but only on router so it probably won't be problem with cable. I have tried connecting through old getnet router, and it doesn't work neither. Back then when i turned router on, i would have to power cycle like 10 times to make it connect to modem.

Comment: @Slavo, two things, first the PC and its NIC may have better power and different chips designed to try to get most from NIC, and more likely has settings you could tweak like forcing 10 meg full duplex.  The cable itself is probably deteriorating.  Oxygen and moisture in the air can change some of the fundamental resistances and this "impedance" may not be something the TP Link can tolerate.  If you TP link and the modem you are plugging into were "managed" devices, you would be able to manually set the speed and test .

Comment: A 80m cable will drastically slow down your internet, modem or router. A wireless adapter might be a better bet.

Comment: Isn't max length for cat 5 actually only 30m?

Comment: 100/1000BASE-T specifies up to 100 Meters over UTP, but that is likely comprimised due to the damage to the cable. OP, understand that cable pin-outs come in several varieties, and one of those is Cross-patch, a cable commonly used to connect a PC directly to a modem or other PC, but that doesn't work correctly for communications with a switch, so that it works with the PC is not a meaningful diagnostic. Further is the concept of Duplex, which will determine what wires are used. usually you would not solder a cable, and you must be careful to preserve isolation between the inner wires.